# TCP - collect data from some days ago

Tags: ubuntu, tcp

I am wondering if it possible to get tcp dumps or any type of information of tcp connections that are some days old

Machine: Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is not normally recorded

If you are using iptables or a similar packet filtering system and if there are suitable rules in place then connections are logged to files in /var/log

Comment: I suspected that, will have to log next time, thanks for the answer.